# ruby on rails: jquery + fancybox + google.maps v3 = IE8 map reloading not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, google-maps, internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I have a few links on my page, I attach google_map in fancybox to them

```
  $('a.fancy_map').fancybox({
    'centerOnScroll' : true,
    'autoDimension': true,
    'onComplete': function(){
      var center = map.getCenter();
      var zoom = map.getZoom();
      $.fancybox.resize();
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      map.setCenter(center);
      map.setZoom(zoom);
  )}
```

Click on link calls action 'map' in the controller and renders map view. The function within 'onComplete' resizes map and places the same center and zoom before - it was needed to show map correctly on second and other clicks to link.

It works ok in all browsers, except IE8 (I didn't test other versions).

I found a [solution that catches error and reloads the page](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e2bcbb06c9c3f89b/d546479ed378cd29?lnk=gst&q=IE8%20reload#d546479ed378cd29), but it's not that usefull as I have fancybox.

IE error message:

```
Ligne: 1
Caractère: 348
Code: 0
Message d'erreur: Invalid argument.
URL: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fr_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/7/1/main.js
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

if the function above is an exact copy and paste of the one you are using then just be sure that you have properly closed all your arguments:

"onComplete" is not closed, it's missing the closing bracket "}" at the end... and the last ")}" should be "});"